# Environment variables get reset between gradle tasks (Jenkins)

Tags: jenkins, gradle, environment-variables

I need to pass environment variables to my executable and my unit tests. This works locally but not on Jenkins. On Jenkins, my environment variable gets reset in between gradle tasks

```
task setupEnv(type: Exec) {
    commandLine 'export', "ABC=def"
}

test {
    dependsOn 'setupEnv'
    scanForTestClasses = false
    include '**/*Test.*'
}
```

Note: I'm simplifying here for SO (I'm aware of the `environment` command in Gradle) but even with this simple example it works locally but not on Jenkins, meaning *Test.java files see nothing for System.getEnv("ABC"). I'm looking at how to not have Jenkins reset environment variables

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to set dynamical env in pipeline. As a result these envs will be available globally (to all stages in the pipeline):

1. set it in a stage

```
    stage('set date') {
      steps {
        script {
          env.ANY_NAME_OF_THE_SCRIPT=sh(returnStdout: true, script: "date +%Y-%m-%d").trim()
        }
      }
    }
```

2. set it in environment

```
    pipeline {
      agent {
        label 'some_label'
      }  
      environment {
        HELLO = """${sh(
          returnStdout: true,
          script: 'echo hello'
            ).trim()}"""
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, actually the weird part is that to test, I had 3 tasks, tasks1 depends on task2 depends on task3 (which sets the env var). Task2 could see the env var set by task3. task1 (which was the test) couldn't... can you help explain that?

Comment: What do you mean "a task"? Is it a job?

Comment: I mean a gradle task

Comment: which type of jobs do you use in jenkins?

Comment: we use the gradle plugin

Comment: yes, it is not possible to use gradle tasks without gradle plugin installed in jenkins. Which job type do you use in jenkins?

Comment: we ask for the gradle wrapper and ask for task "test". It also works when using ./gradlew test from jenkins bash